# Notification Service implementation for sending mails

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am working on one Asp.Net application and need to send mails periodically based on some event. First I thought of creating a thread in global.asax and start thread in application_start. But that becomes a bit of problem when application pool crashes or something. So I implemented a windows service and started thread in that and log any errors in windows event log. This works fine. But I need to know whether I am implementing it correctly or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Windows Service for this kind of tasks is the preferred way instead of doing it in the ASP.NET application. You may also take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which could simply your code for scheduling the task execution and dealing with threads. But if you don't want to write Windows Services probably the simplest would be to have a console application that will do the job of sending emails and then simply use the Windows Task Scheduler to run it at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are moving (or moved already) to the right direction.

We have similar architectures as well, in some cases we used MSMQ to queue outgoing notifications from the ASP.NET application then the Windows Service, usually called Messaging Manager, can grab **asynchronously** the incoming messages and send the emails or alerts out.

this proves to be effective and robust, if anything crashes after the message has been queued, nothing will be lost because the windows service will always process the messages in the queue, so you can have ASP.NET recycling or the machine with the windows service being rebooted, nothing is lost ever. And in fact in normal production mode, messages are sent out instantly, the decoupling or loose of sync is mostly hidden when everything is working smooth and servers are not overloaded or suffering anything.

In a later project we are now implementing something similar using TIBCO technologies, EMS for the queues and Business Works for queue subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a message-based approach. You could have a Windows Service/Console Application reading messages of a message queue (like msmq) and send email when a message is recieved. You can then have your ASP.NET application publish messages to this queue.

[Minibuss](https://github.com/johandanforth/MiniBuss) is a lightweight client for msmq which is very easy to work with. Another options is [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/).